# Why NotNull annotation doesnt work Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have several annotations that work, only @NotNull doesn't. When I try to save a contact with empty name, it saves. If needed I can upload the view file.
Here is my entity class(only the part with @NotNull annotation).

```
@Entity
```

public class Contact {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotNull
private String name;
```

}

Here is the controller class:

```
@Controller
```

public class ContactController {

```
@Autowired
private ContactRepository contactRepository;

@GetMapping("/addContact")
public String addContact(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
    return "addContact";
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public String add(@ModelAttribute @Valid Contact contact, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "addContact";
    }
    contactRepository.save(contact);
    return "addContact";
}
```

}

Comment: Empty string does not equal null so if you don't want an empty string as `name` use `@NotEmpty` or `@NotBlank` instead.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have taken partly my code from here spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input , it should be working but idk why it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, use the annotation `@NotBlank` instead. A blank String is not null - e.g `String s = ""`. `@NotBlank` will demand at least one non-whitespace character.

Here is the [javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html):